# Upload file to GDrive in php without user intervention

Tags: google-drive-api, google-oauth

I am using google-drive-sdk to upload a pdf file (dynamically generated in the php web app) to Gdrive.

### About my app

On click of submit button the users see a THANKYOU displayed on the page. At the background

1. pdf file gets generated
2. and this file needs to be uploaded to Gdrive account --(configured the client id & secret key for the app in Google Console)
   :

I am able to upload to the configured GDrive but first time to authenticate I run the url(redirect url given in Google Console) in browser(*say

> http://localhost:3422/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/mktProc/google-api-php-client/gDrive_access/pdf_results_upload.php

*)
This takes me to GDrve page and prompts Allow\Deny Access.

I click Allow and then am able to upload to Grdive.

But I would like this to happen without prompts for Allow\Deny for the user to interact.

Please give me details on what I need to add so that when user clicks the Submit button , automatically the generated file gets inserted to GDrive.

I read lot in net but couldn't understand and get it to work.
Please help me with steps and code to include. 
The code I am using

```
                <?php

                include_once "templates/base.php";
                if(!session_id()){session_start();}

                require_once realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../autoload.php');

                $pdf_filename='';
                try
                {
                  if(isset($_SESSION['pdf_filename']) && $_SESSION['pdf_filename']) 
                      $pdf_filename=$_SESSION['pdf_filename']; 
                }
                 catch(Exception $ex)
                 {
                      echo ("This is for GDrive Upload from CalWeb");
                 }
                $pfdStoragePath=dirname(__FILE__)."/../../vendor/pdf/".$pdf_filename;
                /************************************************
                  ATTENTION: Fill in these values! Make sure
                  the redirect URI is to this page, e.g:
                  http://localhost:8080/fileupload.php
                 ************************************************/

                $client_id = 'xxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com';
                $client_secret = 'xxxxSB0tNVy';
                $redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:3422/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/mktProc/google-api-php-client/gDrive_access/roi_results_upload.php';
                $client = new Google_Client();
                $client->setClientId($client_id);
                $client->setClientSecret($client_secret);
                $client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
                $client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive");
                $client->setAccessType("offline");
                $client->setApprovalPrompt('force'); 
                $service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

                if (isset($_REQUEST['logout'])) {
                  unset($_SESSION['upload_token']);
                }

                if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
                  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
                  $_SESSION['upload_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
                  $redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
                  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
                }

                if (isset($_SESSION['upload_token']) && $_SESSION['upload_token']) {
                  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['upload_token']);
                  if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
                    unset($_SESSION['upload_token']);
                  }
                } else {
                  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
                }

                /************************************************
                  If we're signed in then lets try to upload our
                  file. 
                 ************************************************/
                try {

                if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
                  if($pdf_filename!=="")
                  {
                  $file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
                  $file->setTitle($pdf_filename);
                  $file->setDescription('Document');
                  $file->setMimeType('application/pdf');
                  $result = $service->files->insert(
                      $file,
                      array(
                        'data' => file_get_contents($pfdStoragePath),
                        'mimeType' => 'application/pdf',
                        'uploadType' => 'multipart'
                      )
                  );
                  //echo $result->webContentLink;
                  $pdf_filename="";
                  unset($_SESSION['pdf_filename']);
                  }

                  //if (isset($result) && $result) $_SESSION['webContentLink']=$result->webContentLink;
                  //echo $result->webContentLink;
                }//if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
                } catch (Exception $ex) {
                    echo '';
                }

                ?>

                <div class="box">
                  <div class="request">
                    <?php if (isset($authUrl)): ?>
                      <a class='login' href='<?php echo $authUrl; ?>'>Connect Me!</a>
                     <?php else: ?>  <?php echo "Access Allowed" ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                  </div>

                  <?php if (isset($result) && $result): ?>
                    <div class="shortened">
                         <?php echo "aaa"; ?>
                      <?php echo $result->webContentLink; ?>
                     <?php echo "bbb"; ?>

                    </div>
                  <?php endif ?>

                    <?php if($pdf_filename==="") ?>
                    <?php echo "This is for GDrive Upload from MiniROI" ?>
                </div>
```

Comment: A user must give you access to upload to their Google drive that's how it works.

Comment: @DalmTo Yes currently it works when the User click the Allow popup

Comment: @DalmTo             Yes currently _GDrive upload_ happens when the return url is first executed in a browser say Chrome, With this 1. it prompts Allow\Deny, 2.User click the Allow in popup- 3.it works. This works only if its executed in the same browser again (Chrome) or  till the cookies are cleared . BUT without any user intervention or atleast one time authenticating, can we upload this generated pdf file to GDrive  whenever a user\guest click the Submit Button.                      It would be really a great help if you can get the steps to address this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to understand how authentication works first then.   You need to have a user grant you access to THEIR data before you can access private data.  You cant just upload to my google drive account unless I tell you that you can.   The user will always have to authenticate your code once if you want to access their drive account.   It will always pop up the first time.  if your user is logged in you could potentially save the refresh token then the next time they login they wont have to re authenticate because you have the refresh token you need to access their account.

Comment: I have a tutorial that explains how google oauth works in more detail. http://www.daimto.com/google-developer-console-oauth2/

Comment: @DaImTo would it be possible to edit your comment to replace all occurrences of "authenticate" with "authorize".

Comment: @pinoyyid wont let me after 5 minutes

Comment: Ok Thanks DaimTo 

I have 2 queries here - 

**Query 1** -- Is there any specifics that approval by the user should be run on server where app is hosted?
**Query 2** ---] How should we save the refresh token to re-use?

Comment: **Query 1**
Lets say the user approves & so click "Allow" in the popup.
But where\which machine should this happen?

Should this action (approval of Access in GDrive - i.e popup Allow\Deny)  happen in the server where the application is hosted 
or 
can it be anywhere from any system (& its that the GDrive understands by this the user has approved access for this app)

Comment: **Query 2**
From your answer I now understand the refresh tokan need to be saved and can be used for next accesses to GDrive by another guests\users
Can you please give me more details on how to save the refresh token and be resused.

I see the refresh tokens in my application as 
"{"access_token":"ya29.Ci9LA_Z7Lyor-Y4jTloppnqTy_ranPisH87X2vPP2edrW_xIGJ2Su2qqFkK6R9UsHA","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":3600,"refresh_token":"1\/iw3EOJ4grLLNO7xtXmvjHXsz5VxbCCAqzDgaN5evMR8","created":1472204033}"

Comment: A1/ The authorization can be done on any server. You need to be clear (plse update your question) whether you wish to upload to (a) the end user's GDrive, or (b) to a GDrive linked to your app. The approach you take is very different for each use case. 


A2/ the refresh token is just a string so you can store it in a server file or database. Just make sure that it's secure as anybody with the refresh token can access the Drive account it pertains to.

Comment: Thanks pinoyyid & DalmTo
I stored the accessToken in a file and now after the first user intervention -- Allow (in Google Request page), the generated pdf file gets saved into the configured GDrve.

Comment: But now I have another problem when moving the code to Staging server.
In Google Developer Console When the origin & return uri is changed to Staging URL it does not take me to the Google Request page --> wher it prompts to Allow\Deny Access to the App - so does not get me the access code back from google drive.
But if I change back the uri to my localhost it works perfectly
What is the mistake I am making here?